# Internet Explorer presenting email error label on page load with jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate, email-validation

I am having a problem with the jQuery Validation plugin and Internet Explorer. Basically, the "Please enter a valid email address" error message is being presented on page load and although all the validation works correctly it is rather unsightly to be there before the user has even entered any data.

If i remove the email class and just make the field required there is no problem but i want it to validate the email address.

I am having this issue in IE7/8/9

Here is my code:

```
//Form Validation
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#rsvpForm").validate({
           rules: {
             // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
             attendance: "required",
             firstname_main: "required",
             lastname_main: "required",

             // compound rule
             email: {
               required: true,
               email: true
             },
             total_guests: {
              required: "#attendance:checked"
            },
             firstname_partner: {
              required: function(element) {
                return $("input:radio[name='total_guests']:checked").val() == '2' || $("input:radio[name='total_guests']:checked").val() == '3' || $("input:radio[name='total_guests']:checked").val() == '4'
              }
            },

             lastname_partner: {
              required: function(element) {
                return $("input:radio[name='total_guests']:checked").val() == '2' || $("input:radio[name='total_guests']:checked").val() == '3' || $("input:radio[name='total_guests']:checked").val() == '4'
              }
            },
             firstname_child1: {
              required: function(element) {
                return $("input:radio[name='total_guests']:checked").val() == '3' || $("input:radio[name='total_guests']:checked").val() == '4'
              }
            },
             lastname_child1: {
              required: function(element) {
                return $("input:radio[name='total_guests']:checked").val() == '3' || $("input:radio[name='total_guests']:checked").val() == '4'
              }
            },
             firstname_child2: {
              required: function(element) {
                return $("input:radio[name='total_guests']:checked").val() == '4'
              }
            },
             lastname_child2: {
              required: function(element) {
                return $("input:radio[name='total_guests']:checked").val() == '4'
              }
            },
           }
        });

        jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
            required: 'Required',
        });
      });
// Submit Handler
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#rsvpForm').ajaxForm({ 
            target:     '#content', 
            url:        'components/process-form-data.php' 

        }); 
    });
```

These are my header links:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript.js"></script>
```

Form HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="components/process-form-data.php" id="rsvpForm">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="attendance">Will you be attending the wedding? <em>*</em></label>
                <div class="radioBtns">
                <input class="signUp" type="radio" value="Yes" name="attendance" id="attendance" />
                <label class="signUp">Yes</label>

                <input class="signUp" type="radio" value="No" name="attendance" />
                <label class="signUp">No</label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <h2>Main Guest</h2>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="firstname_main" class="standard">First name<em>*</em> :</label>

                <input type="text" name="firstname_main" id="firstname_main" placeholder="First name" />             
            </fieldset>             
            <fieldset>
                <label for="lastname_main" class="standard">Last name<em>*</em> :</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname_main" id="lastname_main" placeholder="Last name" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="email" class="standard">Email<em>*</em> :</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
            </fieldset>
            <div id="guests">   
            <fieldset class="wideField">
                <label for="total_guests">Will you be bringing a partner and/or young children? <em>*</em></label>
                <div class="radioBtns">
                <input class="signUp" type="radio" value="1" name="total_guests" id="total_guests" />
                <label class="signUp">No</label>
                <input class="signUp" type="radio" value="2" name="total_guests" />
                <label class="signUp">Just Partner</label>
                <input class="signUp" type="radio" value="3" name="total_guests" />
                <label class="signUp">Partner + 1 young child</label>
                <input class="signUp" type="radio" value="4" name="total_guests" />
                <label class="signUp">Partner + 2 young children</label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div id="partnerDetails" style="display:none;">
            <h2>Partner Details</h2>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="firstname_partner" class="standard">First name<em>*</em> :</label>

                <input type="text" name="firstname_partner" id="firstname_partner" placeholder="First name" />             
            </fieldset>             
            <fieldset>
                <label for="lastname_partner" class="standard">Last name<em>*</em> :</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname_partner" id="lastname_partner" placeholder="Last name" />
            </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div id="childDetails" style="display:none;">
            <h2>Child Details</h2>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="firstname_child1" class="standard">First name<em>*</em> :</label>

                <input type="text" name="firstname_child1" id="firstname_child1" placeholder="First name" />             
            </fieldset>             
            <fieldset>
                <label for="lastname_child1" class="standard">Last name<em>*</em> :</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname_child1" id="lastname_child1" placeholder="Last name" />
            </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div id="secondChildDetails" style="display:none;">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="firstname_child2" class="standard">First name<em>*</em> :</label>

                <input type="text" name="firstname_child2" id="firstname_child2" placeholder="First name" />             
            </fieldset>             
            <fieldset>
                <label for="lastname_child2" class="standard">Last name<em>*</em> :</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname_child2" id="lastname_child2" placeholder="Last name" />
            </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div id="diet">
            <fieldset class="wideField">
                <label for="dietaryRequirements">Do any of your guests have special dietary requirements :</label>
                <textarea cols="55" rows="8" name="dietaryRequirements" id="dietaryRequirements"></textarea>
            </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input id="submit_btn" input="" type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" class="btn" />            
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your form in IE8 with no problem. If you see the email field error message on the initial page load in IE7/9, try the previous version of the plugin:
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for you reply but that didn't seem to help but I think i've isolated the problem.

I also have some code in my page that populates placeholder text in IE. As i was using "Email" as my placeholder text the validation was firing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you reply but that didn't seem to help but I think i've isolated the problem.

I also have some code in my page that populates placeholder text in IE. As i was using "Email" as my placeholder text the validation was firing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        $(function() {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            if(('placeholder' in input)==false) { 
                $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
                    var i = $(this);
                    if(i.val() == i.attr('placeholder')) {
                        i.val('').removeClass('placeholder');
                        if(i.hasClass('password')) {
                            i.removeClass('password');
                            this.type='password';
                        }           
                    }
                }).blur(function() {
                    var i = $(this);    
                    if(i.val() == '' || i.val() == i.attr('placeholder')) {
                        if(this.type=='password') {
                            i.addClass('password');
                            this.type='text';
                        }
                        i.addClass('placeholder').val(i.attr('placeholder'));
                    }
                }).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
                    $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                        var i = $(this);
                        if(i.val() == i.attr('placeholder'))
                            i.val('');
                    })
                });
            }
        });
        /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this one?

Comment: Right i've solved it and feel pretty stupid now.

I had the placeholder code after the validation which meant that when the placeholder text was added it fired the real time validation. 

Simply the placeholders needed to be loaded first. I.e. placing the JS before.

Comment: I've just had this issue and putting the modernizr script above the validate script has fixed it! thank you :)